# What git commands is GitHub using when you delete a branch from the website interface?

Tags: git, github

I used the GitHub website to delete a branch from a list of branches (red trashcan icon in image below).

[image]

When I fetch latest of origin master on my local machine and then executed `git branch -r`, I can still see the deleted branch in remote. But when I run `git ls-remote --heads origin`, the branch and its head isn't there.

What exactly is GitHub doing?

Comment: When you fetch, is it on a clean copy of the repo?

Answer (score 3):

These are actually two separate questions, but I'll try to answer both of them. First, when you delete a branch in the GitHub interface (or using the GitHub API), it does the equivalent of `git branch -D`. However, it doesn't use that specific command to do so; most hosting providers use libgit2 to interact with the repo.

The reason you're seeing the remote branch still on your machine is that a `git fetch` command doesn't delete remote tracking branches unless you use `--prune`.  If you use `git fetch --prune origin`, then the deleted branches will be removed.

Answer (score 3):

`git fetch` doesn't remove remote-tracking refs by default. Run [`git fetch --prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt--p), then `git branch -r` again. They should be gone.

> Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote.